# Can abrt help to gather information about process issues

Tags: abrt

We have a system (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6)
where we occasionally see hung java processes (xalan or fop transformations).

These processes just sit there and never complete

In /var/log/messages I find entries like this

```
abrt[33580]: Saved core dump of pid 48556 (/usr/bin/jdk1.6.0_06/bin/java) to /var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2017-06-01-08:52:40-48556 (341344256 bytes)
abrtd: Directory 'ccpp-2017-06-01-08:52:40-48556' creation detected
abrtd: Executable '/usr/bin/jdk1.6.0_06/bin/java' doesn't belong to any package and ProcessUnpackaged is set to 'no'
abrtd: 'post-create' on '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2017-06-01-08:52:40-48556' exited with 1
abrtd: Deleting problem directory '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2017-06-01-08:52:40-48556'
```

- Can abrt be used to gather extra information about the issues ?
- Is it useful to change ProcessUnpackaged to yes ?

Answer (score 1):

If the process is `aborted` or has a `coredump`, it will no longer be in memory anymore. So if you think a process is hung, get the `pid` of the process, and run the following :

`strace -fp <pid> -o strace.out` -- can be useful to point out the system call at which the process might be hung (refer the output file strace.out).

`pstree -aAp <pid>` -- shows the current executing line from the program.

```
/usr/bin/gdb -q -p <pid> -- to see the current state of the process.
```

If you have the `coredump` available,you can use `gdb` to analyse it.

```
/usr/bin/gdb <java_binary_path> <coredump_path>
```

And on `gdb` console use:

`(gdb) bt`

`(gdb) thread apply all bt`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll try it , You don't mention abrt. Does this mean that abrt cannot help ?

Comment: If the process is hung, let it be, because analysing it in that state would give precise info as to why it was hung and so on.If aborted it would be off the memory and you would have to analyse it with the only `coredump` it might leave you with.